# How do I output an array into the display in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, 2d, 2d-games

I'm creating a game in which if a certain condition is met it will add the rect inside the array

`tail.append(pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (350, 350, 25, 25)))`

and while it did really add it in the array when I printed the array in the console, but the rect disappears immediately from the display game. I figured out that its because it only shows in when the the condition is met but after the coordinates changes it'll disappear which is only a second.

Answer (score 1):

The entire scene has to be redrawn in each frame. You need to draw the rectangles in the main application loop. Create a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object and append it to `tail` when the condition is met:

```py
tail.append(pygame.Rect(350, 350, 25, 25))
```

However, draw all the rectangles in `tail` in the application loop:

```py
while True:

    # [...]

    for rect in tail:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), rect)

    # [...]
```